# Extracting text that is beneath a heading, to be stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, string

I need help with extracting text that is beneath a heading, to be stored in a dictionary. Let me elaborate, I have a text file with information organized the following way:

HEADING 1 (The heading is always written in all caps, there may be instruction like sentence this written enclosed in brackets beside the heading, the contents within the bracket will be excluded):

*Subheading 1:*

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

*Subheading 2:*

3. Item 3
4. Item 4

*Subheading n:*

3. Item *n*

HEADING 2 (this is the second heading that will be extracted and stored in the dictionary):

*Subheading 1:*

1. Item 1
   ...

I wrote the following function:

```
def extract_info(corpus):
    # Initialize variables
    output = {}

    # Extract info
    for element in corpus.split("\n\n"):
        item = element.split("\n") 
        key = item[0].split("(")[0].replace(":", "").strip()
        output.update({key:item[1:]})
    
    # Return output
    return output
```

Unfortunately, this only gets the first subheading (Subheading 1) and ignores the rest. What can I do?

Comment: use regex, it is more reliable and robust

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it is doing. When I print out the output, I get:

```py
{'HEADING 1': [], 'Subheading 1': [], 'Item 1': ['    Item 2', ''], 'Subheading 2': [], 'Item 3': ['    Item 4'], 'Subheading n': [], 'Item n': [], '': ['HEADING 2 (this is the second heading that will be extracted and stored in the dictionary):']}
```

which I'm pretty sure is not what you want.
After splitting the text based on `\n\n`, you get:

```py
['HEADING 1 (The heading is always written in all caps, there may be instruction like sentence this written enclosed in brackets beside the heading, the contents within the bracket will be excluded):', 'Subheading 1:', '    Item 1\n    Item 2', 'Subheading 2:', '    Item 3\n    Item 4', 'Subheading n:', '    Item n', '\nHEADING 2 (this is the second heading that will be extracted and stored in the dictionary):', 'heading 1:', '    Item 1\n    Item 2\n']
```

from which you then try to get the items by splitting each element again using `\n` delimeter. Here, you should instead have checks to make sure the current element is what you expect by coming up with rules(robust enough for your requirements).

My suggestion would be to keep some variables to keep track of the current heading(s),subheading(s) and update them as you traverse the text and build your `dict`.

Here is what that might look like.(Note: This function does not account for all edge cases)

```py
def extract_info(corpus):
    # Initialize variables
    output = {}
    # print(corpus.split("\n\n"))
    # Extract info
    curr_heading = ""
    curr_subheading = ""
    curr_subheadings = {}

    for element in corpus.split("\n\n"):
        element = element.split("(")[0].strip()  # Remove comments
        # print("e: ", element)
        # print(curr_heading, curr_subheading)
        if element.isupper():  # It's a heading
            if curr_heading:
                output[curr_heading] = curr_subheadings
                curr_subheading = ""
                curr_subheadings = {}

            curr_heading = element
        elif element[-1] == ":":  # It's a subheading
            curr_subheading = element
        else:
            curr_subheadings[curr_subheading] = element.split("\n")

    output[curr_heading] = curr_subheadings  # Last bits

    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above post, I found a simpler solution to the problem:

```
def extract_info(corpus):
    # Initialize variables
    output = {}
    heading_key = ""

    # Extract info
    for element in corpus.split("\n\n"):
        item = element.split("\n") 
        key = item[0].replace.split("(")[0].replace(":", "").strip()
        if key.isupper(): 
            heading_key = key
            output.update({heading_key:item[1:]})
        else:
            output[heading_key] += ["\n"] + item
    
    # Return output
    return output
```